# How to serve precompressed gzip/brotli files with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, gzip, brotli

Im trying to serve precompressed gzip/brotli files for html, js and css.
With the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on

    # Brotli
    # If the web browser accept brotli encoding… 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} br
    # …and the web browser is fetching a probably pre-compressed file…
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(css|html|js)
    # …and a matching pre-compressed file exists… 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.br -s
    # …then rewrite the request to deliver the brotli file
    RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.br
    # For each file format set the correct mime type (otherwise brotli mime type is returned) and prevent Apache for recompressing the files
    RewriteRule "\.css\.br$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
    RewriteRule "\.html\.br$" "-" [T=text/html,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.br$" "-" [T=application/javascript,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]

    # Gzip
    # If the web browser accept gzip encoding… 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    # …and the web browser is fetching a probably pre-compressed file…
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(css|html|js)
    # …and a matching pre-compressed file exists… 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
    # …then rewrite the request to deliver the gzip file
    RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz
    # For each file format set the correct mime type (otherwise gzip mime type is returned) and prevent Apache for recompressing the files
    RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
    RewriteRule "\.html\.gz$" "-" [T=text/html,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=application/javascript,E=no-brotli,E=no-gzip]

    <FilesMatch "\.(css|html|js)\.br$">
        # Prevent mime module to set brazilian language header (because the file ends with .br)
        RemoveLanguage .br
        # Set the correct encoding type
        Header set Content-Encoding br
        # Force proxies to cache brotli & non-brotli files separately
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|html|js)\.gz$">
        # Serve correct encoding type
        Header set Content-Encoding gzip
        # Force proxies to cache gzip & non-gzip files separately
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
```

My Folderstructure looks like this:

- .htaccess
- index.php
- /css/
- /css/main.css
- /css/main.css.gz
- /css/main.css.br

But I get 404s when using the code above.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the RewriteBase fixed it.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing this to help others. I had to add `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in the `RewriteCond` to get it to work.

Essentially, change all `RewriteCond` to

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.br -s
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was, that brotli compression is not supported for http connections. See [Why is Brotli not supported on HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862412/why-is-brotli-not-supported-on-http)